# Find an actual ? in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find an actual ? in a range of cells.  I am using this code:

```
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rArea As Range

' set range variable = Column in the active sheet.
    Set rCell = Range("g1")
    Set rArea = Range("g2:g" & countusers)
    For Each rCell In rArea
    With rCell
    Dim Qmark As Integer
        If InStr(1, (rCell.Value), "~?") > 0 Then
       MsgBox "Cell " & rCell.Address & "has a question mark in it"
        Qmark = Qmark + 1
        End If
```

I put the ~ in front of the question mark but it's not working.
thanks in advance

Comment: The `InStr` method doesn't require the tilde `~`, so just remove that.  You only need the tilde if you're using the `Range.Find` method

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  i added:

```
Dim SearchChar as String
SearchChar = "?"
```

then replaced "~?" in the InStr line with SearchChar and it worked